# IronPython & WPF. Как программно менять Image.Source?

Tags: python, wpf

Как в процессе выполнения программы менять значение Source элемента Image?
Есть элемент:

```
 <Image x:Name="img"  Source= "D:\test.gif" />
```

Нужно задать:

```
self.img.Source = ?
```

Comment: Вот [такое](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3787280/276994) не помогло? (не знаю, какой там синтаксис на IronPython)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С ответом помогли англоязычные коллеги:

```
from System import Uri
from System.Windows.Media.Imaging import BitmapImage

uri = Uri("D:\\test.gif")
self.img.Source = BitmapImage(uri)
```